# Random numbers to button

Tags: java, android

[image]

How can I put random numbers to button in Android studio with Java? Thank you beforehand.

I wanna put random numbers 4x4 button.

I tried this code but it shows Array list in button:

```
private LinearLayout container;

int[] ran={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    container = findViewById(R.id.container);

    shuffleArray(ran);

    for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) container.getChildAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++) {
            Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(j);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            button.setText(Arrays.toString(ran));
            button.setTextSize(24);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a bit hard to digest your question with no context as to what your actual layout looks like.  You may want to edit your question and fill us in on those details.

Comment: What should be the length of random string?

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.util.*;
     class IntasString{
         public static void main(String args[]){
           int min=1,max=15,result;
           int myarr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
          int range=(max-min)+1;
          result=(int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
          String indexValue=String.valueOf(myarr[result]);
          System.out.println(indexValue);

         }
     }
Use this code according you and use variable indexValue to set text for Button
```